# UIStackView inside a subview programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, addsubview, uistackview

I've got a  `ViewController` that has a lot of labels that must be displayed horizontally, so I've decided to use `UIStackView` for this.
These labels belong to different "sections", so I'm using nested stack views to achieve this. The problem is that one of these "sections" should be displayed with a different background color than the others.

I've read in another thread that `UIStackView` does not have a background color, and I should add the stack view inside a `UIView` and set a proper background color to it.

What I've made so far:

- Create a `UIView` and set its color
- Create a sub stack view and add some labels to it.
- Add the sub stack view to the colored `UIView`
- add the colored `UIView` to the main stack view.

The result: I'm not seeing any of those views inside my view controller.

Note: I need to do this programmatically.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: remember that, in short, you need to set the width of a stack view to the width of the grandparent ...